# Ionic 3: onSMSArrive event not getting triggered (Read sms on android)

Tags: cordova, ionic3

I am trying to integrate `cordova-plugin-sms` plugin to receive and read sms. The watcher is successfully getting started but **`onSMSArrive` callback fails to execute.** I am checking if PERMISSION.READ_SMS is granted if not I am making the user to grant permission for the same.

I am registering the event listener like so

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
                        document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', function(e: any) {
                            var sms = e.data;
                            console.log("received sms " + JSON.stringify( sms ));
                            alert("message received");
                            if (sms.address == 'IG-TAGORE') //look for your message address
                            {
                              this.otp = sms.body.substr(0,4);
                              this.stopSMS();
                              this.verify_otp();
                            }
                        });
                        this.receiveSMS();
                    });
```

This is how I am starting the watch

```
if(window.SMS) window.SMS.startWatch(function() {
            alert("watch started")
        }, function(){
          alert('failed to start watch');
        });
        else {
          alert('plugin not ready');
        }
```

Dependency versions

```
"cordova-plugin-sms": "^1.0.5",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
"@angular/core": "5.2.11",
"@ionic-native/core": "~4.18.0"
```

Comment: On what platform/os are you testing on?

Comment: on android platform only